# Convert a list of matrices to a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector, igraph

I wrote a code to find the distance between neighbors of all adjacent vertices in a graph using [neighbors function](http://igraph.org/r/doc/neighbors.html) and [distance function](http://igraph.org/r/doc/distances.html).

I have a loop to read all edges in the graph and after that to find the distance between every pair of neighbors for the adjacent vertices.
The output of the function `distances()` is a matrix, for example if I have 5 edges then I will get 5 matrices each matrix will contain many distances according to the number of neighbors for each vertex in the selected edge, whereas I want to get only one matrix containing all distances between neighbors(which are 33 distances in my example) to convert it into a vector or from the beginning to get the outputs of the function `distances` as a vector using a loop.

```
library(igraph)
data<-matrix(c(1,3,1,4,2,3,2,4,3,4),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
dataf<-as.data.frame(data)
df <- graph.data.frame(d = data, directed = FALSE)

   for (edge in 1:length(E(df))){
      v1<-ends(graph = df, es = edge)[1]
      v2<-ends(graph = df, es = edge)[2]

      n1<-neighbors(df,v1,mode=c("all"))
      n2<-neighbors(df,v2,mode=c("all"))

      ds<-distances(df, v = n1, to = n2, mode = c("all"))

         for (i in 1:length(n1)){
             for (j in 1:length(n2)){
               #print(ds[i,j])

                                     }
                                 }  
                                 }
```

I failed in all trials to get all ditances in one matrix or to define a loop so that I can store the distances in a vector.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: What about `shortest.paths(df)`? Or `distances(df,1:4,1:4,mode="all")`.

Comment: @nicola This code is a part of another code where [ shortest.paths(df) ] and [ distances(df,V(df),V(df),mode="all") ] will not help me especially when I want to measure the distance between neighbors of a certain edge vertices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
dsList<-list()
for (edge in 1:length(E(df))){
  v1<-ends(graph = df, es = edge)[1]
  v2<-ends(graph = df, es = edge)[2]

  n1<-neighbors(df,v1,mode=c("all"))
  n2<-neighbors(df,v2,mode=c("all"))

  ds<-distances(df, v = n1, to = n2, mode = c("all"))
  dsList[[edge]]<-ds

  for (i in 1:length(n1)){
    for (j in 1:length(n2)){
      #print(ds[i,j])

    }
  }  
}
```

is this the result you look for?

```
> unlist(dsList)
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 2 1 2 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: and is there another way so that I can collect all small matrices in one big matrix?

Comment: well matrix cannot take matrices as elements. check here http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/matrix. dsList contains individual matrices and usually in R we use lists to store more complex data structures (matrices, data frames, other lists, etc)